# How to convert soap xml response to delimited

Tags: groovy, soapui, cdata

I don't know hardly anything about XML. I have successfully gotten a SOAP response (using things like SOAPUi and Boomerang) from an `asmx` web service.  It's a large file.

Now I need to get it to regular delimited columns.  Is there a simple way to do this?

My file is attached [here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0BzU5xb14i1fsVlZlNU5QRG9zNnc/view?usp=sharing)

Comment: You want to try http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm? There is `CDATA` in the xml. So, you need to exact only that part which is the actual data set as input to the above one.

Comment: I was trying that site - and I've also figured I needed to remove some of the stuff about soap, etc., at the beginning and end.  I swear I've tried everything I can think of, and all of the xml-to-columns type of software just errs out.  I"m not sure what I'm doing wrong still.  I actually find the 'csv' a bad idea in the first place, because what if there are commas naturally occurring in the data ? but - i've tried other sites that let me specify pipe delimter - everything.  Can you please specify what I should remove - & is it just removing something at beginning/end, or all throughout?

Comment: I have tried your data on the mentioned site and it has generated the records in comma separated manner, but it took time because of large data. I also wanted to tell you that it is possible to do that using groovy script as well. But see if you could the above mentioned site and get away with it? And other factors such as how frequently this has to be done etc.

Comment: Are you sure you looked at the results final though? When I did it it was just junk. Everything was on one line.

Comment: Yes, did see data. You need take the data which is inside of cdata.

Comment: Ahh!!  that last bit of advice was wonderful - that's what I was not understanding.  Once I made sure to utilize only the data inside of the CDATA[] thing, everything worked perfectly - and in fact, even Excel would simply "import" it (data>from xml> select file - everything worked!).  Thank you very much!  should your comment be an 'Answer'?  You deserve credit for being the person willing to help me - thank you much!

Comment: Thank you for kind words, and nice of you. Added an answer with `script` approach, please see if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure if it is required one time transformation or do this job quite frequently.

So, adding the answer here with some more details.

**Approach #1:** Using on-line

As mentioned in the comments, you can use the [on-line site](http://www.convertcsv.com/xml-to-csv.htm) to convert your `xml data into csv`.

Even it requires to do some pre-process with the message / response that you have i.e.,

- save the data into file
- remove headers or unwanted data etc or make it ready to be usable in the above mentioned online site.

The **disadvantages** in this approaches

- requires some manual work
- expose data on public, but at times may be possible to share
- time taking
- can not use it an automated fashion
- difficult to repeat

**Approach #2:** Using *Groovy Script*

So, this approach addresses the disadvantages of #1 approach.

Here is the Groovy Script which reads previous soap request step's response, and gives the data into a `csv` file.

- In your test case, add a new `groovy script` *test step* **right after the soap request step** which gives you the data and copy below script content into it. i.e., 
  (Test Case -> 
  Step 1: Soap Request where you are getting response
  Step 2: Groovy Script (with below script))
- Add a test case custom property, say `OUTPUT_FILE_NAME` and provide the file path for csv to be saved at. Even, if you do not provide this property, it will automatically saves the csv file `chargedata.csv` under System temp directory.

You may find the comments in-line

```groovy
/**
* this script will read the previous step response
* extract the cdata at the given xpath
* read all the records and transfroms into csv file
**/

import com.eviware.soapui.support.XmlHolder
import groovy.xml.*

/**Define the output file name in test case custom property say OUTPUT_FILE_NAME and value as absolute file path
* otherwise, it write a file chargedata.csv in system temp directory
**/
def outputFileName = context.testCase.getPropertyValue('OUTPUT_FILE_NAME') ?: System.getProperty("java.io.tmpdir")+ '/chargedata.csv'

//csv field separator - change it if needed
def delimiter = ','

/**
* Below statement will fetch the previous request step response. 
*/
def response = context.testCase.testStepList[context.currentStepIndex - 1].testRequest.response.responseContent

//Create the xml holder object to get the xpath value which cdata in this case
def responseHolder = new XmlHolder(response)
def xpath = '//*:Charges_FileResponse/*:Charges_FileResult'

//Get the cdata part from above xpath which is a string
def data = responseHolder.getNodeValue(xpath)

//This again parses the xml inside of cdata
def chargeRecords = new XmlParser().parseText(data)

//This is going hold all the data from ChargeRecords
def chargeRecordsDataStructure = []

//This is to hold all the headers
def headers = [] as Set

/**
* This is to create Charge data
**/
def buildChargeDataStructure = { charge ->
    def chargeDataStructure = new Expando()
    charge.children().each {
        def elementName = it.name()
        def elementText = it.value().join()
        chargeDataStructure[elementName] = elementText
        //Add to field name to the list if not already added
        (elementName in headers) ?: headers << elementName
    }
    chargeDataStructure
}

/**
* this is to create a csv row in string format
**/
def createRow = { recordDataStructure ->
    def row = new StringBuffer()
    headers.each {
        if (row) {
            row += delimiter + recordDataStructure[it] ?: ''
        } else {
            row += recordDataStructure[it] ?: ''
        }
    }
    row.toString()+'\n'
}

//Build the whole data structure of Charge Records
chargeRecords.Charge.each { charge ->
    chargeRecordsDataStructure << buildChargeDataStructure( charge )
}

//Build the rows
def rows = new StringBuffer()
rows << headers.join(',') +'\n'
chargeRecordsDataStructure.each { rows << createRow (it)}

//Write the rows into file
new File(outputFileName).text = rows
```